# Using recursion to get all files in some directory

Tags: c++, winapi

I try to write application that find all files in current diretory and it's subdirectories. I have next problem I can't completely understand

1. How I need use recursion `GetFiles()` function in my case, and
2. Where I need free memory that was dynamically allocated in `PathCreator()` function. When I'm testing this program only for some directory (without subdirectories) it works (look commented code in `_tmain()`). But when I'm try to get all files there is crash.

Here is my code:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 300

int is_directory(wchar_t *p)
{
    wchar_t temp[300];
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while(*p != '\0')
    {
        temp[i] = *p;
        p++;
        i++;
    }
    temp[i] = '\\';
    i++;
    temp[i] = '\0';
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_hendle = FindFirstFile(temp, &file);
    long error = GetLastError();
    if(error == 267)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


wchar_t *PathCreator(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *fileName)
{
    wchar_t* path = new wchar_t[SIZE];
    int j = 0;
    while(j < SIZE)
    {
        path[j] = '\0';
        j++;
    }
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while(*dir != '*' && *dir != '\0')
    {
        path[i] = *dir;
        i++;
        dir++;
    }
    wchar_t *t = fileName;  
    while(*t != '\0')
    {
        path[i] = *t;
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    path[i] = '\0';
    return path;
} 

wchar_t* allFlsArr[SIZE];
int i = 0;
wchar_t **GetAllFiles(wchar_t* dir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_hendle = FindFirstFile(dir, &file);
    if(search_hendle)
    {
        do
        {
            wchar_t *p = PathCreator(dir,file.cFileName);
            allFlsArr[i++] = p;
        }
        while(FindNextFile(search_hendle, &file));
        allFlsArr[i] = '\0';
    }
    CloseHandle(search_hendle);
    return allFlsArr;
}

void GetFiles(wchar_t *dir)
{
    wchar_t **filePaths = 0;
    filePaths = GetAllFiles(dir);
    int  i = 0;
    while(filePaths[i] != '\0'){
        if(!is_directory(filePaths[i]))
        {
            std::wcout << filePaths[i] << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            GetAllFiles(filePaths[i]);
        }
    }
    delete [] filePaths;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    /*wchar_t **wch = GetAllFiles(L"C:\\*");
    int i = 0;
    while( *wch != '\0')
    {
        std::wcout << *wch << std::endl;
        wch++;
    }*/
    GetFiles(L"C:\\*");
}
```

Comment: barring a LOT of unnecessary code, (1) you're not accounting for '.' and '..', both of which are returned by the FindXXXX family of functions you're using. you do NOT want to enumerate those. (2) this is UB as soon as you reach the 301'st file.

Comment: There are huge numbers of problems with this code. Look at is_directory for a start. It's got a buffer overrun. It leaks a search handle. And fails to check the retrun value of FindFirstFile. The by hand string work is just bizarre.

Comment: @David Heffernan If there were no problems with this code, I woudn't share it there. Thanks for helping. I've already know syntax of 'voila'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I wonder why you never use functions like `wcscpy`, `wcscat` or ... and always do all string and buffer manipulation by hand!? but beside that you have some problems in your code:

- You use a single array of wide string pointers(`allFlsArr`) to return result of `GetAllFiles` to the caller and when you are iterating that result you will call `GetAllFiles` again that will overwrite `allFlsArr`.
- You are freeing result of `GetAllFiles` using `delete[] filePaths` but that is actually `allFlsArr` that is a global variable and can't deleted. Try `std::vector<std::wstring>` that do not need `delete/new`.
- Your array of file names is so small that can't accept the files in a folder that have more than 300 files or folders, Again try `std::vector<std::wstring>` that can grow in size and accept any number of items!
- when you search a folder using `*`, Windows return to extra directory that you should never search them (`.`, `..`). You should just skip them (`if(!wcscmp(file.cFileName, L".") || !wcscmp(file.cFileName, L"..")) continue`)
- You use `CloseHandle` to close the handle that returned from `FindFirstFile` while you should use `FindClose`.

So you may have something like this:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> list_files( wchar_t const* folder )
{
    std::wstring root = folder;
    if( folder.back() == '*' ) folder.erase( folder.end() - 1 );
    if( folder.back() != '\\' ) folder.push_back( '\\' );

    std::vector<std::wstring> res;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE hSearch = FindFirstFileW( folder, &file );
    if( hSearch != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        do {
            if( !wcscmp(file.cFileName, L".") ||
                !wcscmp(file.cFileName, L"..") )
                continue;
            res.push_back( root + file.cFileName );
            if( file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) {
                // search for sub folders of this folder
                std::vector<std::wstring> tmp =
                    list_files( (root + file.cFileName) + L"\\*" );
                // all all items to end of our result!
                res.insert( res.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end() );
            }
        } while( FindNextFileW(hSearch, &file) );
        FindClose( hSearch );
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I know that using STL this is task is much more easear, but how I can do it in C plain way?

Comment: Just correct errors that I mentioned, my sample use STL but correcting errors you can still work without STL( for example replace `CloseHandle` with `FindClose` and return result in a new array instead of global array or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean "C plain way"? Your program is in C++!!

Comment: @Vsevywniy: `lstrcpy` and `lstrcat` functions are part of the Win32 API, available to all Windows programs regardless of language.

Comment: @BigBoss: Skipping all folders beginning with `.` may not be the correct approach.  Folder names such as `.svn` are quite common -- it isn't clear from the question whether these should be processed or skipped.

Comment: @BenVoigt As you see in my sample I use `wcscmp` to compare the filename with '.' or ',,' and not just the that started with '.'!

Comment: @BigBoss: I'm looking at the code snippet in your bulleted list.

Comment: @BenVoigt you are just write about that, but look at my example, I will edit my answer!

Comment: @David Heffernan I mean that I can change cout to printf, new to malloc() function... and vuala we have a C code. So I cannot use STL.

Comment: These requirements need to be in the question and not in comments. It still fails to explain why you won't use standard functions for C string operations. Your code is a train wreck. FWIW, the word is voila.